# Testing what method is called based on branch conditions - everything tested except the controller is behind an interface

Tags: c#, moq

I'm pretty new to unit testing, and I have a method that returns a Func based on some branching logic. My issue is, the unit test can't see what method is actually called, perhaps because it is testing the interface. I have to explicitly write in the setup what method will be returned, however I think this defeats the purpose of the test for me since I want to test that the correct method is returned in the branch logic.

This is the method definition in the interface:

```
Func<Task<IEnumerable<T>>> GetMethod(int param);
```

and it returns one of these three:

```
Task<IEnumerable<T>> MethodOne();
Task<IEnumerable<T>> MethodTwo();
Task<IEnumerable<T>> MethodThree();
```

Here is how I set it up in the test, problem is even when I make the actual code return MethodTwo when it should return MethodOne, the test still passes because of this. However, if I don't set it up this way, the test will only see GetMethod being called :(

```
var service = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IGetMethodInterface>>();
            service.Setup(i => i.GetMethod(It.IsAny<int>()))
            .Returns(() => service.Object.MethodOne());

var sut = fixture.Create<MethodController>();
await sut.CallGetMethod();

service.Verify(i => i.GetMethod(It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once());
service.Verify(i => i.MethodOne(), Times.Once());
```

The sad part is, AutoMoq doesn't like concrete classes being used with Verify - so I can't go and use a concrete class implementation in the test:

Here is where its called in the controller:

```
result = await methodInterface.GetMethod(5).Invoke();

return Ok(result);
```

Is there any way to test this correctly using an interface? Or I should definitely test a concrete class? If the concrete class is the only approach, how do we check that a class method is called? I dunno anything like the Verify() method in AutoMoq.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decide whether you're writing a unit test for the controller, or an integration test for the system consisting of the controller and the "method getter".

If the former, you're not interested in testing the logic behind the `IGetMethodInterface` and you should simply test that whatever mock implementation returned is invoked by the controller.

If the latter, you should set up a real controller calling a real implementation of `IGetMethodInterface` without any mocks.

Comment: I see, thank you for that. So what I should do is unit test the implementation of the method getter itself. The controller just relays the work to these method getters anyways

Comment: Without knowing the details of your system, I generally wouldn't unit test a method as simple as the controller method seems to be, where as it sounds like the method getter has more interesting logic and is more relevant to test.

Comment: Yes the GetMethod has the interesting logic, I actually only wrote a few unit tests. I said to my superiors I'll only write unit tests about tricky methods, and not cover everything like some do - lucky they agreed on that one